# How do I install a mesos plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, mesos, mesosphere

I want to install a plugin on my mesos cluster  :

```
http://jenkinsci.github.io/mesos-plugin/
```

The mesos-jenkins plugin require access to a mesos executor (`/usr/lib/libmesos.so`).

I am trying to mount it on my host as a volume so I can use it in jenkins by mounting it on jenkins.

See example [here](https://carlossg.github.io/presentations/assets/mesos-plugin1.png)

[image]

It does not work, I have the following error:

```
ERROR: for panteras  Cannot start service panteras: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:359: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:54: mounting \\\"/usr/lib/libmesos.so\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2cd649dab477b8b743a967642847a0579a733a87163a37aad94154200ebb183d/rootfs\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2cd649dab477b8b743a967642847a0579a733a87163a37aad94154200ebb183d/rootfs/usr/lib/libmesos-1.2.0.so\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
 : Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Do you know how I could get through?

Comment: Can you show your container configuration. Error indicates there is a problem with mounting directory.

Comment: It is because mouting `libmesos.so` is just not enough for this to work. I think the message is pretty straightforward. I have tried to build mesos lib as described in the documentation. Should I install mesos within jenkins container  in order for this to work ?

Comment: Why do you think mounting libmesos.so in a way that your jenkins framework is able to locate it would not be enough?

Comment: Because it is not enough. See the error message. I have installed mesos for debian in the jenkins container. I am able to register with mesos but the slave failed to connect to master. any Idea why this was working in standalone mode?

Comment: Can you update the question with most recent configuration and logs? I suspect you have similar problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43798848/1387612) but it's hard to say without logs.